# sql - count total rows with fields containing a particular comma separated value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Q.1) Suppose I have a table named `advertisements` with a field `ad_memberships` containing comma separated 1,2,3,4 type values and I want to calculate the total number of rows for each values then how can I do that? Like say total rows in the table containing value 1 is 10, 2 is 5, 3 is 15, 4 is 3 etc., without manually inputting the data in FIND_IN_SET() function? I just want to automatically calculate for all. Here, `1,2,3,4` is coming from a table named `memberships` where these are the unique IDs of different rows `mbs_id`.

Q.2) This is related to the first question and both needs to be done together. I am writing it separately so that it is clear and understandable. So, suppose I also have a second table named `ads_category` with fields `ac_id` and `ac_value`. This `ac_id` is inserted in 1st table `advertisements` in the field `ads_category` so that all ads are relevant to some different category. Now after calculating the rows in the 1st question I want to multiply is `ac_value` with the number of rows received in first question and display the result as follows.

```
Standard Membership: 10 ads (Value: $5)
Premium Membership: 16 ads (Value: $12)
Elite Membership: 8 ads (Value: $7)
Ultimate Membership: 11 ads (Value: $8)
and so on....
```

This means for members with standard memberships 10 ads are available for members holding premium membership 16 ads are available and so on. How can I accomplish that? For an example, the database structure is given below:

table: memberships

```
mbs_id | mbs_name
   1   | Standard
   2   | Premium
   3   | Elite
   4   | Ultimate
```

table: advertisements

```
ad_id  | ad_memberships | ad_category
   1   | 1,2            | 1
   2   | 1,2,3          | 1
   3   | 1,3            | 2
   4   | 2,3            | 3
```

table: ads_category

```
ac_id | ac_value
   1  | 0.5
   2  | 1
   3  | 1.5
   4  | 2
```

Expected result from the above database structure

```
Standard : 3 ads (Value: $1.5)
Premium  : 3 ads (Value: $3)
Elite    : 3 ads (Value: $4.5)
Ultimate : 0 ads (Value: $0)
```

Now I want to join all the three tables and get the relevant result. And yes, no values can be entered manually in the query. All should be done with the values in the database. How can I do that? I am using PDO. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857024/searching-a-column-containing-csv-data-in-a-mysql-table-for-existence-of-input-v

Comment: @TimG How to make it automatic? Here, I need to enter the values manually if I use `select Id
from Item
where
  instr(concat(',', Features, ','), ',AB,') <> 0 or
  instr(concat(',', Features, ','), ',PQ,') <> 0` query and that values can increase, decrease or removed too

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite see how your formula is supposed to work, because the example results you show in your question don't seem to match the sample data. But maybe this will give you an idea how to get started.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    m.mbs_name,
    '  Membership: ',
    COUNT(a.ad_id),
    ' ads ($',
    SUM(c.ac_value)
    ')'
  ) AS result
FROM memberships AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN advertisements AS a ON FIND_IN_SET(m.mbs_id, a.ad_memberships)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ads_category AS c ON a.ad_category = c.ac_id
GROUP BY m.mbs_id
```

Comment: thanks for your time but it didn't help. Instead I found the solution. My answer is posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the solution myself. This is my achieved expected output

[image]

CODE:

```
<div class="row">
  <?php
    $mbs = $pdo->prepare("SELECT mbs_id, mbs_name, mbs_color, mbs_perclick FROM memberships");
    $mbs-> execute();

    while($mbsid = $mbs->fetch()){ extract($mbsid);
    $adstotal = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, SUM(ac_value) FROM advertisements
    LEFT JOIN ads_category ON ads_category.ac_id = advertisements.ad_category
    WHERE INSTR(CONCAT(',', ad_memberships, ','), ',".$mbs_id.",') <> 0");
    $adstotal-> execute();
    $adsf = $adstotal->fetch();
  ?>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <span class="membership-indicator" style="background: <?php echo $mbs_color; ?>; margin-top: 5px"></span>
      <?php echo $mbs_name; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
      <?php echo $adsf['cnt']; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
       $<?php $cps = $mbs_perclick/100; $finalval = $adsf['SUM(ac_value)']*$cps; echo number_format($finalval,4,'.',','); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```